# How to mock marklogic client api using jest test framework in typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking, node-modules, marklogic, ts-jest

I am new to typescript, please have a look at following typescript snippet:

```
const marklogic = require("marklogic");
var dbRead = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(connection);
const qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
dbRead.documents
      .query(
        qb.where()
        .slice(0, 10000)
      )
      .result()
      .then(function (documents: { forEach: (arg0: (document: any) => void) => void; length: string; }) {
// do something here
})
    .catch(function (error: any) {
      // handle error
    });
```

I am unable to mock above snippet using jest in typescript, I tried something like following but it didn't work for me:

```
const marklogic = require('marklogic')
jest.mock('marklogic')
const documents = {
  query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(() => { [ { uri: '/anypath', content: ''} ] })
}
describe('should verifyfunction', () => {
    test('should return value from function', () => {
      marklogic.createDatabaseClient.mockImplementation(() => {
        return { documents : documents };
      });
})
})
```

My package.json has following dependencies:

```
"marklogic": "^2.9.1",
"jest": "^29.4.2",
"ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
```

Any help here will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to mock above typescript snippet:

````
var marklogic = require('marklogic');

jest.mock('marklogic', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  createDatabaseClient: jest.fn(() => ({
    documents: getMockedDocument()
  })),
  queryBuilder: jest.requireActual("marklogic").queryBuilder
}));

function getMockedDocument() {
  const docContent = '<_parent><id>c1</id><data>Sample Text</data></_parent>';
  const results = [{ title: 'Document 1', uri: '/anypath', content: docContent },
  { title: 'Document 1', uri: '/anypath', content: docContent }];
  return {
    query: jest.fn(() => ({
      result: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(results)
    }))
  };
}```
````